# how to fix framaroot :exploit work but installation of super su and su binary fail

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

4.2.2 cherry mobile cherry jelly and I'm trying to find some rooting access applications to root my
Phone, and then i found the framaroot, after that it works perfect I have super su installed in my device after that I try to factory reset my device, and then I installed the framaroot again when I press some selection like boromir and it says  :exploit work but installation of super su and su binary fail: plss help me guys I want to root my phone again :-( .[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to root with aragorn. If you have installed supersu from the playstore delete it completely. And don't forget to turn on USB debugging and allow unknown sources.

Edit:

Here is a rooting method for cherry:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2286251

Comment: Hey techmod what version is framaroot with aragorn

Comment: Actually you can choose directly in framaroot from the dropdown menu. You can also try toweloot or kingroot.

Comment: The towelroot and kingroot doesn't work for my android

Comment: Use the link above